# Is the train between Shanghai and Hangzhou smoke-free?

Tags: trains, china, shanghai, smoking

Is [the high-speed bullet train between Shanghai and Hangzhou](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/china-trains/high-speed/shanghai-hangzhou.htm) smoke-free?

Or does it have any smoking seats entirely separated from the normal seats?

I don't mind it if it has smoking seats but I definitely don't like it if there is a restroom for smokers, not seats, and smokers go there and return back stinking.

If it is difficult to escape it, is there any alternative public transport option other than a taxi?

Comment: Since when is *any* part of China smoke-free?

Comment: @RobertColumbia During and after the Beijing Olympic many restaurants and cafes went smoke-free, at least indoor (esp in Beijing). The public transport is also smoke-free. The school is also smoke-free I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, all high-speed trains in China are smoke-free.  Not only is smoking is punishable by fines of up to 2000 yuan, but repeat offenders are banned from using trains!

http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/china/2016-08/16/content_26490229.htm

Comment: While on other trains in China non-smoking rules are often ignored, I haven't seen anybody smoking on a high-speed train.

Comment: Oh, wonderful! I wish the punishment is executed properly...

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Really? And it is *"often"*? I haven't seen anybody smoking on a normal train. It is prohibited and people observe it. Well at least I saw one person smoke on the platform, but never on a train.

Comment: @Blaszard - my last time on trains in China was in 2015, maybe it is better now. Lots of people smoked between carriages and the doors could not be closed, train staff didn't do anything about this.